# Проверка условия не работает как ожидается

Tags: java, условия

Подскажите, почему в данном коде СРАЗУ срабатывает ELSE, никак не могу понять:

```
class Transformer {
public String trans(String s) {
    String[] arabsk = {"0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11"};
    for (int i = 0; i < arabsk.length; i++) {
    }
    String[] rimsk = {"I", "II", "III", "IV", "V", "VI", "VII", "VIII", "IX", "X", "XI"};
    for (int j = 0; j < rimsk.length; j++) {
        if (s.equals(rimsk[j])) {
           s = "5";
        }else{
           s = "12";
        }
    }
    return s;
}
```

Comment: Ваш метод всегда будет возвращать "12". `else` не сработает только в одном случае - если вы передадите в `trans()` строку "I", то есть на первой итерации будет проверка `s.equals(rimsk[j])` , где s = "I" и rimsk[j] = "I" значит сработает `if`, но тут зачем то присваиваете s значение "5" и тогда на следующей итерации сработает `else`, потому что в массиве rimsk нет арабских цифр (то есть "5") и вы опять непонятно зачем присваиваете s значение "12", потом на каждой следующей итерации так как в массиве rimsk нет "12", в s будет снова записываться "12". Напишите здесь, что должен выполнять метод

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < arabsk.length; i++) {
    if (s.equals(arabsk[j])) {
       return rimsk[i];
    }
}
return null;
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]